# Velocity DisplayTool doesn't work

Tags: velocity, xdocreport

Is any way to use Velocity DisplayTool in ODT template (rendered with XdocReport). I linked libraries with maven but when i render report from template I see tag `$display.stripTags(Object)`, it seems that velocity does not recognize this tag.

Is there a need to make special configuration in xml, I use spring but I don't want velocity view resolver bean as it is in many solutions.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `$display` variable will only be available within your template if you have added it to the velocity context.

There are 2 ways I know you can do this:

- You can add an instance of the display tool to the context as a variable before rendering the template
- You can create an xml configuration file and configure a `ToolManager` ([example](http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-create-custom-tools-for-apache-velocity/))